# Javascript/Underscore won't skip undefined result

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to skip a line of code if there is nothing to do. However, I receive the error: `TypeError: _.pairs(...)[0] is undefined`. Why do I still receive this error? the function `conditionalFilter` is supposed to skip if it is `undefined`

Code:

`conditionalFilter(_.pairs(_.pairs(_.pairs(d.nodes[0].children)[0][1].children)[0][1].children)[0][1].dimension, d.dimension.name, d.name)`

Function:

```
function conditionalFilter(check, dim, filter){
if (check != "undefined") {
  myFunction(check, dim, filter);
} else {}
}
```

If it makes a difference, the error throws on the line `conditionalFilter(_.pairs...)`

Comment: I think the issue is you're just missing a `typeof`, and are comparing the variable against the string `undefined`

Comment: @Katana314 thanks for the input. Unfortunately, `(typeof(check) != "undefined")` throws the same error

Comment: @Katana314 is correct. Also, if `check` can be other falsy values (e.g. false, 0, etc) and you still don't want to process, then you could just say `if(check){ myFunction ... `

Comment: Hm, actually a blank line isn't undefined, come to think of it.  So you might want to verify the condition you're checking.

Comment: @Paul `if(check){ myFunction ...` throws the same result also. I was thinking it might be an issues with evaluating `_.pairs()[0]` inside other `_.pairs()`?

Comment: Sounds like the issue has nothing to do with the check, but the fact that _.pairs is not returning anything and you try to reference the array that is undefined.

Comment: @epascarello yes I think so. But I thought if `_.pairs` is not returning anything then `conditionalFilter` would just skip it and move on... is that not correct?

Comment: Not when you reference an index of something that does not return anything. Basically you have `var x = undefined; var foo = x[0]`

Comment: @epascarello oh hmm... do you have a suggestions to get around that? would I have to check if every `_.pairs()` is defined?

Comment: @As3adTintin ``(_.pairs() || [undefined])[0])``?

Comment: Well I would change it just because what you have is unreadable.

Comment: @epascarello ok i'll work on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the quotes off of undefined,

the way you have it now you are checking it as a string:

```
function conditionalFilter(check, dim, filter){
if (check != undefined) {
  myFunction(check, dim, filter);
} else {}
}
```